# Download a file from REST API with Restangular request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, restangular, restify

I've got a simple **node.js** + **Restify** backend with standard CORS settings and this endpoint:

```js
var file = '1,5,8,11,12,13,176,567,9483';

server.get('/download', function(req, res, next) {
  res.set({"Content-Disposition": "attachment; filename='numbers.csv'"});
  res.setHeader("Content-type", "text/csv");
  res.send(file);
  return next();
}, function(err) {
  res.send(err);
});
```

What it's suppose to do is to is to create CSV file and return it.

It works great when I simply type in the endpoint address to web browser and hit enter. The file gets downloaded properly.

But when I try to do the same thing, but instead of using browser's address bar I use Restangular like that:

```js
Restangular.one('download').get().then(function (res) {
    console.log(res);
});
```

it just writes response to console, but no file is being downloaded.

Is there a way to do this using Restangular? Or maybe I need to use something else for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am not sure if Restangular can do that, but I am using [FileSaver](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) script for stuff like that. Add Filesaver to your HTML head and then:

```
Restangular.one('download').get().then(function (res) {
    var file = new Blob([res], { type: 'text/csv' });
    saveAs(file, 'something.csv');
});
```