# Download file from API using javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file, blob, restangular

I need to force download of file using JavaScript. I am using Angular and restangular to communicate with API. I am now working on file download action from API... API returns me raw bytes of that file and these headers:

```
Content-Disposition:attachment; filename="thefile"
Content-Length:2753
```

So I have raw bytes, but I do not know how to handle it to download this file to client...Can you provide me some solution of this issue? How can I handle returns response from server to open in client browser Save As dialog?

EDITED:
Server does not send me content-type of the file...Also in call's headers need to be auth token so I cannot use direct open window with url..
Code is:

```
vm.downloadFile = function(fileId){
 var action = baseHelpers.one('files/' + fileId + '/content').get();
 action.then(function(result){});
}
```

Comment: Include your code calling the API.

Comment: Try reading this: http://paxcel.net/blog/savedownload-file-using-html5-javascript-the-download-attribute-2/

Comment: What's your content-type?

Comment: if you use restangular you can check this example - http://gon.to/2013/04/09/restangular-new-angular-framework-to-handle-restful-resources-properly-and-easily/

Comment: edited with code... content type is not being sent from api

Comment: No of yours links suite for my situation....I tried google but nothing found... Think that its impossible, or not??

Answer (score 3):

I had an endpoint on **.Net server**

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/tagExportSelectedToExcel")]
```

and a **React** frontend with **axios**. The task was to add a button which downloads a file from this API. I spent several hours before found this solution. I hope it will be helpful for someone else.

This is what I did:

```
axios('/api/tagExportSelectedToExcel', {
    data: exportFilter,
    method: 'POST',
    responseType: 'blob'
}).then(res => resolveAndDownloadBlob(res));
```

Where **resolveAndDownloadBlob**:

```
/**
 * Resolved and downloads blob response as a file.
 * FOR BROWSERS ONLY
 * @param response
 */
function resolveAndDownloadBlob(response: any) {
    let filename = 'tags.xlsx';
    filename = decodeURI(filename);
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = url;
    link.setAttribute('download', filename);
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    link.remove();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My first guess would be: Just request that API URL directly and not with an asynchronous request. You should be able to do something like this in your code

```
$window.location = "http://example.org/api/download"
```

For a solution using RESTangular I found [this snipped](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular/issues/479), maybe you can try it:

```
Restangular.one('attachments', idAtt).withHttpConfig({responseType: 'blob'}}.get({}, {"X-Auth-Token": 'token'}).then(function(response) {
    var url = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(response);
    window.open(url);
});
```

Comment: ah ok.. then it would be nice to remove the downvote since this information was not given in your original answer ;)

Comment: edited my answer for using with RESTangular.. maybe you can give this a try :)

Comment: doesn't work with this... I used google a lot but no answer found... have you another idea?

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31820506/download-a-file-from-rest-api-with-restangular-request?rq=1 .. Filesaver.js is used there for serving the data as download, but basically it's the same approach. Check your response and that you've a valid blob object if this solution doesn't work for you either.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to answer without seeing your code calling the API, but in general the way you do this is to send a *form* rather than using ajax. Typically you'd have a hidden iframe with a `name="downloadframe"` or similar, and then use a form like this:

```
<form id="downloadform" target="downloadframe" method="POST" action="/the/api/endpoint">
<input type="hidden" name="apiParameter" value="parameter-value">
</form>
```

Then you'd fill in the fields of the form and submit it programmatically. Here's an example not using Angular, but adapting it would be simple (though not necessary):

```
var form = document.getElementById("downloadform");
form.apiParameter.value = "appropriate value";
form.submit();
```

When the browser gets the response, it sees the `Content-Disposition` header and asks the user where to save the file.

You can even build the form dynamically rather than using markup if you prefer.

Comment: cannot be done because in headers in calls to API I need send also auth token...code is simple: restangular.one('files/' + fileId + '/content').get();